# Access: Group by and then split data into columns

Tags: ms-access, group-by, ms-access-2016

I have the following data in Access. It represents an original request being sent to someone. If the request is not fulfilled, it is re-launched (for as many times as it takes to be filled, I think the max so far is around 5).

```
|REQUEST #| EMAIL_ID |    EMAIL_SUBJECT      | DATE_SENT|
|---------|----------|-----------------------|----------|
|    1    |    1     | 1- blah blah          | 01-01-18 | 
|    1    |    3     | 1- blah blah          | 01-06-18 |  
|    2    |    75    | 2- this               | 01-07-18 |   
|    2    |    100   | 2- this               | 01-10-18 |    
|    2    |    102   | 2- this               | 01-14-18 |
```

In this example, emails 3, 100, and 102 are re-launches. I would like to GROUP BY request # and have the original date, number of re-launches, first re-launch date, second re-launch date, etc as columns

It would look like this:

```
| REQUEST_# | DATE_SENT_ORI | #_OF_REL | REL1_DATE | REL2_DATE  | ETC...  |
|-----------|---------------|----------|-----------|------------|---------|
|    1      |   01-01-18    |     1    | 01-06-18  |   null     |   null  |
|    2      |   01-07-18    |     2    | 01-10-18  |  01-14-18  |   null  |
```

I recognize that it will likely be some mix of a count and a group and possibly min and max calculations but can't get the right combination.

I would be greatly appreciative if someone could help me sort this out.

Comment: Should be a straight forward SELECT min(Date_SENT) as Sate_sent_ORI ....  group-by Request_#. Where is your exact problem and what doesn't go as you planned? What did you do so far?

Comment: Although oin second thought, having every date as a separate field is not trivial. The question is, why you need it. Do you want to create another table? a report?

Comment: So I can find the minimum date, but I don't know how to find the minimum date +1, then +2, then +3, for the re-launches

Comment: For a report. First, I need to know how many times it was relaunched. But also, when we get replies to these requests, I need to count the time in between the (most recent) request/relaunch being sent and the reply.

Comment: Can you make do with the number of releases, the 1st date and the last date?  That's a much simpler request.

Comment: I wish, but unfortunately not. I need to measure the time in between every reply and the most recently created/re-launched request, so i need to know the date of every re-launch.

Comment: Seems a bit more than you stated in the question. Could you edit it and show where the replies come in? In Reports you can group by request_IDs and have line by line of the resent emails easily...

Answer (score 0):

I like to use a 2 step process for clarity, although you can probably combine these into one query if you want to.

I named the table Sample and used this query to get the index of each request - this gives a number from 1(first request) to n(final request).  I saved this as Sample_Indexed

```
SELECT Sample.[REQUEST #], Sample.EMAIL_ID, Sample.EMAIL_SUBJECT, Sample.DATE_SENT, (select count(*) from Sample T where T.[Request #]=Sample.[Request #] and T.Date_Sent<=Sample.Date_Sent) AS [Index]
    FROM Sample;
```

Then I did a 2nd query to move the data into columns:

```
SELECT Sample_Indexed.[REQUEST #], Sample_Indexed.EMAIL_SUBJECT, Max([Index]) AS [Count], Max(IIf([index]=1,[Date_Sent])) AS Date_1, Max(IIf([index]=2,[Date_Sent])) AS Date_2, Max(IIf([index]=3,[Date_Sent])) AS Date_3
FROM Sample_Indexed
GROUP BY Sample_Indexed.[REQUEST #], Sample_Indexed.EMAIL_SUBJECT;
```

In this 2nd query you can add as many Date_N columns as needed.  You can also do a simple query from Sample_Index to find the max Index that you need to accomodate in the 2nd query.

Comment: @Jayme_123 - was this helpful, or do you still have questions?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've misunderstood your requirement, using a crosstab query should get you most of the way there:

```
TRANSFORM 
    First(DATE_SENT) AS DS
SELECT 
    [REQUEST_#], Min(DATE_SENT) AS DATE_SENT_ORI, Count(EMAIL_ID) AS [#_OF_REL]
FROM 
    myTable
GROUP BY 
    [REQUEST_#]
PIVOT 
    DATE_SENT
```

Obviously changing `mytable` to suit your data source.

Comment: Actually, it may be more suitable to use this after assigning the indexes per Don George's answer.

Comment: A Crosstab becomes awkward if there are subsequent steps, and it sounds like there will be calculations of elapsed time between the dates later in the work process.